# Introducing Immutable.js into redux/react code

Tags: immutable.js

I'm introducing Immutable.js into my redux/react project. I'm changing the likes of:

```
let {id, name} = user;
```

to:

```
let id = user.get('id');
let name = user.get('name');
```

That's twice as much code. Is there any way of coding the latter in a more concise manner?

Comment: Does `let { id, name } = user.toJS();` work?

Comment: Don't use `.toJS()` like that, it is a rather expensive operation to just get a few values.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use destructuring with an Immutable.js `Map`, at least not right out of the box. If your project uses Babel, you can add a plugin called [babel-plugin-extensible-destructuring](https://github.com/vacuumlabs/babel-plugin-extensible-destructuring).

After configuring that, you'll be able to use destructuring and something like this will work:

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
const map = fromJS({author: {name: {first: "John", last: "Doe"}, birthdate: "10-10-2010"}});
const {author: {name: {first, last}, birthdate}} = map;
```

Also, note that something like `List` is an iterable and therefore can be destructured like a regular array.

For example:

```
const list = List(['Hello', 'World', 'This', 'Is', 'a', 'List']);
const [first, second, ...theRest] = list;
console.log(first);
> "Hello"
console.log(second);
> "World"
console.log(theRest);
> ["This", "Is", "a", "List"]
```